# eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to develop an eclipse plugin. Which is the best way to start?

Answer (score 3):

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) is a good place to start. Then you might expand your knowledge by reading one of the more recent Eclipse RCP books, such as "[Practical Eclipse RCP Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001VNCF3K)". I personally started off with the tutorial about RCP that comes with the Eclipse SDK, so might want to check it out as well - it's basically a shorter version of the first tutorial I recommended you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to use the **[Eclipse RCP package](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)**, specifically designed to build a rich client application.

[image: RCP Icon]

See this [Eclipse packages comparison table](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php).

Answer (score 2):

I have found the book [Eclipse Plugins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462) to be a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse: Building Commercial-Quality Plug-ins (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228472) is a good book.

Comment: Looks like the 4th edition is coming soon: http://www.amazon.com/Eclipse-Plug-ins-4th-Eric-Clayberg/dp/0321774159/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: But it looks like the 4th ed isn't due until February 25, 2012.  The 3rd is available now.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[**Contributing to Eclipse**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321205758) should be a very good choice.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is also a good start:
http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Eclipse PDE Documentation, I've found this pdf to be very useful in gaining better understanding regarding the plugin development.

Plugin Exercies (http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/csu670/f05/project/PluginExercises.pdf)

Solving these exercises will really help.