# How to create my own XML Editor with design tab and source tab?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin, editor, swt

Following is an xml Editor with design tab and source tab:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/topic/com.ibm.etools.xsdeditor.doc/images/ncalxml.gif

I'd like to create such an editor using SWT, that is, I'd like to develop a **Eclipse plugin**: XML Editor. I hope the XML editor includes a design tab and a source tab, just like the Screenshot above. and I'd like to develop the xml editor using java swt. And I need a tutorial about developing xml editor.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you need help with SWT? Do you need help with parsing XML do build that tree structure? Do you need help with parsing text files in general? What is it **concrete** that you want to ask?

Comment: I'd like to develop a plugin: XML Editor. I hope the XML editor includes a design tab and a source tab, just like the Screenshot above. and I'd like to develop the xml editor using java swt. And I need a tutorial about developing xml editor.

Comment: A plugin for what platform? Neither SWT nor JFace are a plattform capable of supporting plugins. It's just a GUI framework.

Comment: I'd like to develop a plugin for Eclipse, I want to develop the UI(design tabe in the screen above) using SWT.

Comment: Is the one provided by Eclipse insufficient somehow, or are you doing this as a programming exercise?

Comment: If you want to develop an eclipse plugin look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703577/eclipse-plugin-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use JFace instead of straight SWT. JFace has taken much of the work of editor creation and manipulation away. Take a look at the MultiPageEditor.

You might want to consider Xtext as well.

Comment: JFace will be OK too. Any tutorial about the XML Editor created by JFace?

Comment: Eclipse for RCP and Plug-in Developers (PDE) comes with a whole host of example editors, including a multi-page editor.

Answer (score 3):

“Begin at the beginning,” the King said very gravely, “and go on till you come to the end: then stop.” (Lewis Carroll - Alice in Wonderland).

This is a large task. You need to divide it in smaller steps, then tackle each one. When you have started, you may have more specific questions to ask.